# SharePoint Online Mega Menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, pnpjs

How can I create a Mega Menu using term-sets in SharePoint online?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to make an own mega menu, look at this repository. There you can find an unbelievable amount of fancy stuff. I guess you will find something suitable for your needs.
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-mega-menu

If you like to modify the mega menu you should look at this post. Maybe that's something useful: https://twitter.com/vesajuvonen/status/1032253273745571840?lang=de